# Batch file to run an executable command inside a directory

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a batch file that would:

1) change to a directory

2) run an executable command that is inside the directory

3) write the output of the execution to a text file

made use of cd to change directory but when i ran the executable command inside the directory it halts.

On code below, snmpset.exe is inside the SNMP folder

```
cd c:\Users\MyComputer\SNMP

START "c:\Users\MyComputer\SNMP\snmpset.exe -r:96.120.97.190 -c:hDaFHJG7 -o:1.3.6.1.4.1.1429.78.1.1001.1.0 -val:1 -tp:int" >> "c:\Users\MyComputer\list.txt"
```

If I ran the command by itself on the cmd line the result is this:

```
SnmpSet v1.01 - Copyright (C) 2009 SnmpSoft Company
[ More useful network tools on http://www.snmpsoft.com ]

OK

c:\Users\ralcal000\Downloads\SnmpSet>
```

Comment: Watch the quotation: `start "" "C:\Users\MyComputer\SNMP\snmpset.exe" -r:96.120.97.190 -c:hDaFHJG7 -o:1.3.6.1.4.1.1429.78.1.1001.1.0 -val:1 -tp:int >> "C:\Users\MyComputer\list.txt"`. Alternatively, use the `/D` switch: `start "" /D "C:\Users\MyComputer\SNMP" "snmpset.exe" -r:96.120.97.190 -c:hDaFHJG7 -o:1.3.6.1.4.1.1429.78.1.1001.1.0 -val:1 -tp:int >> "C:\Users\MyComputer\list.txt"` (no more need for `cd [/D]`)...

Comment: If you have already `C`hanged `D`irectory, _(`CD /D "%UserProfile%\Downloads\SnmpSet"`)_, then you do not need to use the full path to your executable, e.g. `Start SNMPSet -r:96.120.97.190 -c:hDaFHJG7 -o:1.3.6.1.4.1.1429.78.1.1001.1.0 -val:1 -tp:int">>..\list.txt"`. You may find that you do not need the `start` command at all, i.e. `SNMPSet -r:96.120.97.190 -c:hDaFHJG7 -o:1.3.6.1.4.1.1429.78.1.1001.1.0 -val:1 -tp:int">>..\list.txt"`, and if `list.txt` doesn't already exist, change **`>>`** to **`>`**.

Comment: ty that works great.

Answer (score 0):

Run the batch file in **c:\Users\MyComputer\SNMP** no need to change directory.